# Responsive website - how to debug a non-responding responsive css?

Tags: css, debugging, responsive-design

I'm working on a project that needs 4 different layouts:

- Desktop+Laptop;
- Tablet landscape;
- Tablet portrait;
- Mobile.

For the testing purposes I'm using Opera browser and its page zooming. And in Opera (as well as all the other browsers on my laptop) when I zoom the page in and out, the layout changes correctly. But when I open the same page with my smartphone and tablet, it just displays the Desktop layout. My project's temporary address is:

http://tiip.dit.rs/tiip2

Does anyone have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some code may make better sense

Comment: I'd gladly leave examples of my code, but I'm clueless about what the problem could be, so I was hoping if someone with more experience could have a look at my entire project. That's why I left the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome if you open up the developer tools, there is a little cog in the bottom right corner. In the settings you can choose user agent, which will make chrome behave similar to different devices . hope this helps [image: Chrome dev tools]

Comment: Thanks a lot Hugo, this is the closest I got to the solution. However if I change the User Agent to iPad, or iPhone, my layout again acts correctly, but on the actual devices Desktop layout is still displayed...

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because it finally helped me debug my existing layout. Thank you Hugo DB.

Comment: Seriously? This does not answer your question. It might be a useful tool for debugging, but without using the viewport meta tag you won't achieve your goal.

Comment: Well @ItayGal that's exactly what my question was: how to debug this problem. I'm sorry if I confused you, all the answers I got helped me in one way or another. But my goal was not to just fix this one problem, my goal was to find out how I can debug this and all the future problems that may occur.

Comment: Your problem : " But when I open the same page with my smartphone and tablet, it just displays the Desktop layout."

Your final question was: "Does anyone have any ideas what am I doing wrong?".

Comment: Just read my actual question please. You'll see it clearly says: "How to debug a non-responding responsive layout".

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can get some more information about this tag and why you need it by googleing
"viewport meta tag"

Answer (score 0):

I think this link may be more helpful to you

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

And for initially to your HTML

**Add**

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Dhaval thanks, but that's exactly the article that I've been following. And it didn't work.